# Is there an API to disable/enable a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

Is there an API call allowing one to enable/disable a Firefox add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [nsIExtensionManager](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/public/nsIExtensionManager.idl) interface.

Comment: It looks like that link is broken now, but it is somewhat described on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Enhanced_Extension_Installation#Little_Things_This_Upgrade_Fixes_or_Changes). Bear in mind that this is not compatible with Fx 4.

Comment: (and too bad I cannot delete an accepted answer that is my own)

Answer (score 5):

Starting from Firefox 4, this can be done via [`AddonManager`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager).

For instance, to *disable* an add-on:

```
AddonManager.getAddonByID(id, function(addon) {
    addon.userDisabled = true;
});
```

To support both Gecko <= 1.9.1 and > 1.9.1:

```
var man = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"];
if (man) {
    man = man.getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager);
}
if (man) {
    man.disableItem(id);
} else {
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
    AddonManager.getAddonByID(id, function(addon) {
        addon.userDisabled = true;
    });
}
```